# Is it possible to use phonegap for just a part of the application?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

Is it possible to use Phonegap for only a part of an application ?

For instance on Android (but my question includes other OS as well), can an Activity use Phonegap components and native components (in the same screen) ?

Thank you.

Comment: A webview doesn't let me use the API that appcelerator provides (accelerometer, camera, ...)

Comment: That's what PhoneGap gives you. Its API includes accelerometer, camera and more. And PhoneGap code runs inside of a WebView

Comment: Don't waste your time, native is better

Comment: I know native is better. The goal is mix native and Phonegap in the same screen, and a webview doesn't provide access to the Phonegap API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The little experience below seem to answer my needs, at least on Android. I guess a similar hack can be made on the other OS.

```
public class TestPhonegapActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        ((ViewGroup) appView.getParent()).removeView(appView);
        linearLayout.addView(appView);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Native");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this seem to only work for TextView? I wrote my own View class and when I add it this way, it covers all of the phone gap stuff.

Comment: I guess my other question would be, how can I allot more space for the TextView in your code? When I run it, the text is given very little screen space.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
```

and then add what you want:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Native");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```